# DB2 jdbc execute function error

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, prepared-statement

Below the code executes a function at DB2. Executing any function at DB2 like INTEGER(x) or MOD(x,y) causes an exception. The exception is:

```
SQLException information
Error msg: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.14.122
SQLSTATE: 42610
Error code: -418
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.14.122
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:677)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.c(oo.java:2715)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.d(oo.java:2703)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.a(oo.java:2136)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.a(po.java:7793)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.h(ab.java:141)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:41)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(p.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.qb.i(qb.java:135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.ib(oo.java:2105)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.uc(po.java:3629)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.b(po.java:4424)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.hc(po.java:756)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.executeQuery(po.java:725)
    at DB2FunctionCall.main(DB2FunctionCall.java:23)
Error msg: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-516, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.14.122
SQLSTATE: 26501
Error code: -516
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-516, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.14.122
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:682)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.c(oo.java:2715)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.d(oo.java:2703)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.a(po.java:3530)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:190)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:84)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.b(p.java:69)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.rb.c(rb.java:244)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.rc(po.java:3521)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.uc(po.java:3630)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.b(po.java:4424)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.hc(po.java:756)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.executeQuery(po.java:725)
    at DB2FunctionCall.main(DB2FunctionCall.java:23)
Error msg: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=4.14.122
SQLSTATE: 26501
Error code: -514
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=4.14.122
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:682)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.c(oo.java:2715)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.a(oo.java:2163)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.o(ab.java:849)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.j(ab.java:267)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.d(ab.java:55)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.c(p.java:44)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.qb.j(qb.java:147)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.kb(oo.java:2158)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.b(po.java:4483)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.hc(po.java:756)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.executeQuery(po.java:725)
    at DB2FunctionCall.main(DB2FunctionCall.java:23)
```

Sample code:

```
public class DB2FunctionCall {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
                String url = "jdbc:db2://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/xxxx";
                String user = "xxxxxx";
                String password = "xxxx";

                Connection con;
                ResultSet rs;

                Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                con.setAutoCommit(false);
                PreparedStatement selectStatement = con.prepareStatement("select INTEGER(?) from sysibm.sysdummy1;");
                selectStatement.setString(1, "1");
                rs = selectStatement.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    int no = rs.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println(no);
                }
                rs.close();
                con.commit();
                con.close();

            }
        }
```

If parameter is removed from prepared statement it is OK. Setting parameter to a DB2 function causes the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that it is working if you hardcode the value : `"select INTEGER('1') from sysibm.sysdummy1;"` ?

Comment: One question is why you are using `setstring()` when it is a numeric value?  You should be using `setint()`.  Using setstring causes the numeric value to be unnecessarily surrounded by quotes in the query.  That being said, `integer('1')` should work as long as the string is numeric.  So it doesn't seem like it should be causing the problem.

Comment: @Berger, yes i mean it.

Comment: @dan1111 INTEGER(x) function is a function that converts string to integer. this is just an example. Like INTEGER(x) function, MOD(x,y) gets the same exception.